# Difference between CSS Keywords and Properties?

Tags: css

Someone asked me what CSS Keywords were and I was confused by this question and thought it might be 
some new feature of CSS3 or LESS, things that I am not really up to date on.

However after googling a bit it seems that CSS Keywords are just CSS properties such as 
background-color:yellow;

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.

A keyword is a pre-defined value that can be used as the value of a CSS property, which combined become a declaration. For example, `left` and `right` are keywords that can be used with the `float` property. There are also other kinds of values that can be used with properties, such as length values (such as `10px` or `20em` for properties like `width` or `height`), strings such as `"hello!"` for properties such as `content`, and functions, such as `rgba()` for the `color` and `background-color` properties. Functions use round brackets to hold additional values.

See the definition of keywords at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#keywords

Comment: CSS2.1 seems to have a much looser definition of keywords, using the term not only for property values but also at-rules.

Comment: yeah, I think at-rules are just called at-rules or rules now. The @font-face uses both of those interchangeably. As does the at-viewport spec. [blocks me from using two "at" in a comment.]

Answer (score 5):

No, `background-color: yellow` is a [declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#declaration), not a keyword.

A [keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#keywords) in CSS2.1 is nothing more than a lone identifier (i.e. a word that isn't surrounded by quotes like a string). A property is the name of the style that you're applying, so in the given declaration the property name is `background-color` and its value is `yellow`.

The identifier `yellow` also happens to be a keyword representing, well, the color yellow, because `'yellow'` as a string is not a valid color value — when specifying names of colors they must always be keywords. In some sense you could say that a "keyword" is equivalent to an "identifier" in terms of the CSS2.1 grammar.

Other examples of keywords include `auto`, `inherit`, `initial` and `none`.

Answer (score 1):

The css keywords are the words that you can add to a css property that are inherit in css as yellow, blue, etc, and the properties are the characteristics you can change in a style...

background-color(property): yellow(keyword)

Answer (score 0):

> background-color:yellow

Here **background-color** comes under **background** property.[See this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/)

Comment: actually, background is a different property. It is a shorthand property, of which background-color is one of its parts.